# Where did Cobra get his psycho-gun?

Tags: cobra

In **Space Adventure Cobra**, a campy space opera series, and in its more recent sequels, Cobra, the adventurous main character, has a cybernetic gun embedded in his left forearm that uses mental energy. We know he wasn't born with it, so how did he acquire the psycho-gun?

[image: Cobra and his cybernetic gun-arm]

Answer (score 1):

He had made the blacksmith of "不知火鉄心 (しらぬい てっしん) (Shiranui-Tesshin)" who live on the earth.
thus, I think answer is the earth.